# Folders should create accoring to email or username and uploded video should be inside that folder

Tags: javascript, php

The files is uploading and the folder is created. But the video is not moving to that specified folder. How can I fix that?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $extension = explode('.', $name);
    $extension = end($extension);
    $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['file']['size'] / 1024 / 1024;
    $random_name = rand();
    $folder = mkdir("$random_name");

    $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


    if ((strtolower($type) != "video/mpg") && (strtolower($type) != "video/wma") && (strtolower($type) != "video/mov")
        && (strtolower($type) != "video/flv") && (strtolower($type) != "video/mp4") && (strtolower($type) != "video/avi")
        && (strtolower($type) != "video/qt") && (strtolower($type) != "video/wmv") && (strtolower($type) != "video/wmv")
    ) {
        $message = "Video Format Not Supported !";

    } else {

        move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder . $random_name . '.' . $extension);
        $conn->query("insert into videos (title,location) values ('$name','$random_name.$extension')");
        $message = "Video Uploaded Successfully!";
    }

    ?>
    <?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message\\n\\nUpload: $name\\nSize: $size\\nType: $type\\nStored in: uploads/$name');</script>";
    ?>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: This is *extremely* dangerous. You're accepting raw user input as your filename. Prepare to get thoroughly hacked.

Comment: Is it any clients requirement ?

Comment: ```$folder = mkdir("$random_name");``` [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) returns boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $random_name . '/' . $random_name . '.' . $extension);
```